# Cordova jsPDF - PDF generated,I can not find the pdf file in Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, jspdf

I'm running in cordova android device,
 I can get to the line 'console.log ("write success");' but I do not think the file does not appear where it is saved.

I've tried running in 2 different androids,
  create a pdf file and save in any folder anywhere

The source code
  http://www.tricedesigns.com/2014/01/08/generating-pdf-inside-of-phonegap-apps/

```
    //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
console.log("generating pdf...");
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

var pdfOutput = doc.output();
console.log( pdfOutput );

//NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
console.log("file system...");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

   console.log(fileSystem.name);
   console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
   console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

   fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
      var fileEntry = entry;
      console.log(entry);

      entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
         writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
         console.log("write success");
      };

      console.log("writing to file");
         writer.write( pdfOutput );
      }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
      });

   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
},
function(event){
 console.log( evt.target.error.code );
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?? I am facing same issue!

Comment: No :{, i need help too

Answer (score 0):

My issue was sorted

[Opening a PDF in cordova javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206408/opening-a-pdf-in-cordova-javascript/37208103?noredirect=1#comment61950350_37208103)

[jsPDF and cordova Cant view the pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185594/jspdf-and-cordova-cant-view-the-pdf-file/37186289?noredirect=1#comment61945171_37186289)

I was trying to write the file to root and access it from there which is not possible in a non rooted phone.