# jsPDF and cordova Cant view the pdf file

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, jspdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF invoice for my app , I can get to the line 'console.log ("write success");' but I just cannot locate the file. Please help!!! How can I save it to a folder in my mobile???

```
console.log("generating pdf...");
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

var pdfOutput = doc.output();
console.log( pdfOutput );

//NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
console.log("file system...");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

   console.log(fileSystem.name);
   console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
   console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);



fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
      var fileEntry = entry;
      console.log(entry);

      entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
         writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
         console.log("write success");
      };

      console.log("writing to file");
         writer.write( pdfOutput );
      }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
      });

   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
},
function(event){
 console.log( evt.target.error.code );
```

Comment: Can you post the result of console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving your files in the root path of the system.

If you want to select the folder, check the [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

So, if you want to select a public folder, so you can check your files outside of your app, check this link

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout

and choose one with private = no.

For example:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
          dir.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
         console.log("write success");
      };

      console.log("writing to file");
         writer.write( pdfOutput );
      }

            },function () {


              console.log("ERROR SAVEFILE");

            });
          });
        });
```

And your file will be placed in you sdcard/files directory

For opening it, I supose that you dont have any pdf viewer plugin, so inAppBrowser is the solution for not having to use any, and open it inside your app

Install [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

And open it:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {


          dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) { //EXISTS
            var url = "file:/" + cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "/test.pdf";
            window.open(url, '_blank');
          }, function() { //NOT EXISTS

          });
        });
```

I haven't tested it, as looks like inAppBrowser dont like too much local files. Please post your results

Comment: i believe there is no such thing like 'cordova.file.file' Please correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: Hey Thank you!! it Worked. My pdf got saved in my app directory.Thanks a million. Can you also suggest how I can open this pdf once its created?? I gave cordova.file.externalDataDirectory. Of course file.file was just an example i suppose

Comment: Ok, I will post it in 1 hour as I am not at home

Comment: How do you want to open it? do you have any pdf viewer plugins as pspdfkit or pdftron?

Comment: @user2281415 Have edited my answer to provide more info on pdf viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the below line could be the issue, **"window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {})"**

In some of the posts i read, it was mentioned that requestfilsystem method along with LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT argument will not work in android unless the device is rooted.

I made it work using - **"window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,successCallback, errorCallback);"**

I suggest you to have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037359/unable-to-delete-file-using-cordova/) where i have posted the same code for file creation in both Android and iOS device.

Also if you wanna open the PDF in application of your choice, you can use cordova file opener plugin. You can have a look the file opener sample code in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629515/cordova-ios-video-tag-local-file-source/)

Comment: Will get back as soon as possible after trying inappbrowser

Comment: @Del its not working..no error is thrown but file is not opened

Comment: yet to try it..I am confused how to give the uri to the file..cdr.nativeURL + "test.pdf", even in in app browser method im getting file not found error..

Comment: @user2281415 My first link in the post have details about cdr.nativeURL. Any error trace?Did you tested on device?

Comment: actually file opener plugin i am not getting any success or error message

Comment: function openFile(cdr) {
  console.log("" +cdr.toNativeURL());
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(cdr.toNativeURL(),
        ,
        "application/pdf", //mimetype
        {
            error: function(e) {
                alert("Error Opening the File.Unsupported document format.");
            },
            success: function() {
                // success callback handler
    alert("success");
            }
        }
    );
}The file is saved in '/Internal Storage/Android/data/com.example.Work2/files/test.pdf'

Comment: @user2281415 Are you not using cordova.file.externalDataDirectory?