# Opening a PDF in cordova javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have generated a PDF invoice using the file plugin. Now I want to open the file in the app. I tried inAppBrowser, but its giving an empty page. I tried fileopener, its neither giving a success or failed message. How do I specify the path to my file . please help!!

In app Browser Method

```
var cdr='';
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
cdr=dir;
alert("cdr "+cdr);
      dir.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) 
      {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
     console.log(" write success");
  };

  console.log("writing to file");
     writer.write( pdfOutput );


        },function () {


          console.log("ERROR SAVEFILE");

        });
      });
    });

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {

alert("open file");
      dir.getFile("test.pdf", {create:false}, function(fileEntry) { //EXISTS

      alert("native url "+cdr.toNativeURL());
        var url =cdr.toNativeURL()  + "test.pdf";
        alert(url);
        window.open(url, '_blank');
      }, function() { //NOT EXISTS
 alert("no file found");
      });
    });

}
```

Fileopener Method

```
 var cdr='';
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory ,     function(dir) {
    cdr=dir;
    console.log(" vidhya cdr "+cdr);
          dir.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) 
          {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
         console.log("vidhya write success");
         openFile(cdr);
      };

      console.log("vidhya writing to file");
         writer.write( pdfOutput );


            },function () {


              console.log("vidhya ERROR SAVEFILE");

            });
          });
        });
    function openFile(cdr) {

    var fs;
    function fsSuccess(fileSystem)
    {
        fs = fileSystem;
        console.log("vidhya "+fs);
    }

    function fsFail(event)
    {
        console.log(event.target.error.code);
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess, fsFail);


        console.log("vidhya opening file " +cdr.toNativeURL());
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
       fs.root.toURL() +'test.pdf',
        "application/pdf", //mimetype
        {
            error: function(e) {
                alert("Error Opening the File.Unsupported document format.");
            },
            success: function() {
                // success callback handler
                alert("success");
            }
        }
    );
    }
```

My file is getting saved in /internal storage/Android/Data/app_folder/files/test.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that the file is getting saved? Did you tried navigating to the file using file explorer?

Comment: its getting saved..I am able to view it outside of app.

Comment: Now you have given a valuable info. In your case file is getting stored inside an application data folder, hence you cant access the file outside the application as application data is protected for outside access. You gotta store in some external folder like i mentioned and try viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone faces an issue while opening the file stored in device even with proper destination file path specified, please do ensure that the file is downloaded properly without corruption.

Many a times file opening fails due to improper or corrupted download. You can also trace any error during download using [chrome inspect devices option](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en). Also ensure to use latest version of file transfer plugin to avoid download error.

Answer (score 3):

This is how i made it work in my hybrid mobile app:

```
var cdr;
sessionStorage.platform = device.platform;
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
} else {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
}

function onError(e) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error : Downloading Failed");
};

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var entry = "";
    if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
        entry = fileSystem;
    } else {
        entry = fileSystem.root;
    }
    entry.getDirectory("Cordova", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
};

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
    dir.getDirectory("My_App", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, onGetDirectorySuccess1, onGetDirectoryFail);
};

function onGetDirectorySuccess1(dir) {
    cdr = dir;
    dir.getFile(filename, {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
};

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    var documentUrl = "http://myserverurl.com/test.pdf";
    var uri = documentUrl;
    fileTransfer.download(uri, cdr.nativeURL + docFileNameToView,
        function(entry) {
            openFile();
        },
        function(error) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Error");
        },
        false
    );
};

function openFile() {
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        cdr.nativeURL + docFileNameToView,
        'application/pdf', {
            error: function(e) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Error Opening the File.Unsupported document format.");
            },
            success: function() {

            }
        }
    );
};

function fail(error) {

    navigator.notification.alert("Error");
};

function errorHandler(e) {

    navigator.notification.alert("Error");
};

function onGetDirectoryFail(error) {

    navigator.notification.alert("Error");
};
```

This code uses cordova file transfer plugin to download pdf and file opener plugin to view the pdf. This sample code also use device plugin to get the device platform (iOS or Android) and dialog plugin to display notification.

Code was tested on iOS 9 and Android 6 devices and works fine. In Android, the file gets stored in `storage/emulated/0/Cordova/My_App` folder

Comment: Thank you..will try and get back..you have transfered the file ?Is that required?

Comment: I am trying to do file transfer now , using your code..but file is not downloaded from the url..Can you help?

Comment: @user2281415 Could you post any error trace and specify info about the issue?

Comment: Actually i am getting download successful message but not able to find the file      `fileTransfer.download('http://cdn.wall-pix.net/albums/art-space/00030109.jpg', cdr.nativeURL+'test1.jpg',
        function(entry) {
   
   console.log(" Successful download...");
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            openFile();
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(" Error4 "+error);
        },
        false
    );`

Comment: @user2281415 Are you testing on iOS or Android? You can alert cdr.nativeURL to find where the file path is and navigate to the path using file explorer to see whether the file has downloaded correctly.

Comment: i am testing in android... path it says storage/emulated/0/cordova/my_app/test1.jpg .External root directory is been accessed.`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);`

Comment: @user2281415 The path seems perfect. Did you navigated to the path in file explorer and verified its download fine without corruption? Also if you are testing on Android 6, you should use latest cordova file plugin(2.2)

Comment: ok..the file is not properly downloaded...some corruption I guess, downloaded another file manager from play store and then it showed up.But its not opening cause its corrupted

Comment: @user2281415 There you got the problem. Now look for the options you are setting for file fownload. Also i m sure that there wil some error in console if you debug in chrome using inspect devices option. Keep me posted.

Comment: Hey thanks for inspect devices option!!! I found that the file open plugin was a diifferent version, due to which it was throwing an error!! Thanks a lot! I never knew about the inspect devices method to debug!!!

Comment: @user2281415 Glad it worked. Can i post the answer so that you can accept the same? May be helpful for others too?

Comment: @user2281415 Posted. Please do accept the answer. Happy coding. Cheers :)