# ng-cordova-file doesn't find created file

Tags: angularjs, cordova

On app launch it checks if a certain file exists, if not then it will make an `http` request to get an `API` in `json` format. If the request is successfully done, then it will create a json file.

The `$cordova.writeFile()` logs in success handler so it must have worked (I don't know how to check if it indeed made one though).

When I close the app and relaunch it then it checks again but it goes always in the error handler `doesn't exist`

```
// On launch    
$scope.checkFile('news.json');

$scope.checkFile = function(file){
  $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, file)
   .then(function (success) {
     console.log('Exists!');
   }, function (error) {
     console.log('Doesnt exist');
     $scope.update();
   });
 }

//If it doesn't exist
$scope.update = function () {
  // Get all news
  NewsService.getAllNews().then(function (data) {
    $scope.saveFile('news.json', data);
    $scope.news = data;
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
};

// Write file

$scope.saveFile = function (file, data) {
  console.log(file) // logs news.json
  console.log(data) // logs data

  $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, file, JSON.stringify(data), true)
   .then(function (success) {
     // success
     console.log('Worked!');
    }, function (error) {
     // error
     console.log('Didn't work'); 
   });
};
```

**Edit:**
`cordova.file.dataDirectory` leads to:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.myname.appname/files/
```

Is this the correct path?

**Edit2:**
Instead of logging my own error, I logged the variable error. It says:

```
FileError {code: 5, message: "ENCODING_ERR"}
```

Comment: Could you try writing to cordova.file.externalDataDirectory instead of cordova.file.dataDirectory? Could be a possible permission issue in android.

Comment: That didn't work either. He goes in error handler as well

Comment: Whats the path you are getting in case of specifying cordova.file.externalDataDirectory? It should be something like "storage/emulated/0"

Comment: It's indeed `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my name.appname/files/`

Comment: Are you testing on Android Marshmallow? If yes, ensure to use latest file plugin

Comment: Yes, version 6.0.1 I think I have the latest file plugin because I installed it yesterday.

Comment: @Gandhi I'm using 4.2.0 version of File plugin

Comment: I m sorry Greg. Its not cordova.file.externalDataDirectory but cordova.file.externalRootDirectory. Request you to check this link for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206408/opening-a-pdf-in-cordova-javascript

Comment: I've tried it, but I'm still getting `error 5: ENCODING_ERR` message

Comment: This should help you out - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ngcordova-checkfile-checkdir-error-code-5-encoding-err/11955

Comment: Did you cracked it?

Comment: I didn't, unfortunately

Comment: Still the same error?

Comment: Yes indeed, I've tried different `cordova.file.*` but no luck